# CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS not working with thrust/cuda

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, thrust

Thrust allows for one to specify different backends at cmake configure time via the `THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM` flag.  My problem is that I have a bunch of `.cu` files that I want to be compiled as regular c++ files when a user runs cmake with `-DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=OMP` (for example).  If I change the extension of the `.cu` files to `.cpp` they compile fine (indicating that I just need tell cmake to use the c++ compiler on the `.cu` files). But if I add `.cu` to `CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS` then I get a `CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "cuda_kernels"`.  Here's a minimal cmake example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

project(kernels LANGUAGES C CXX Fortran)

set(KERNELS_USE_OMP OFF)
if ("${THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM}" STREQUAL "OMP")
  set(KERNELS_USE_OMP ON)
endif()

# verify CUDA support
include(CheckLanguage)
check_language(CUDA)
if (CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER AND NOT KERNELS_USE_OMP)
  enable_language(CUDA)
else()
  list(PREPEND CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS "cu;CU")
endif()

message(STATUS "${CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS}")

find_package(Thrust REQUIRED CONFIG)
thrust_create_target(Thrust FROM_OPTIONS)


add_library(cuda_kernels my_kernels.cu)
target_link_libraries(cuda_kernels Thrust)
```

The output of the `message` command on my system is: `-- cu;CU;C;M;c++;cc;cpp;cxx;mm;mpp;CPP;ixx;cppm`

Why is cmake not respecting my `CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS` changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is cmake not respecting my `CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS` changes?

The extension-to-language for `<LANG>` is set as soon as `<LANG>` is enabled by inspecting the value of the `CMAKE_<LANG>_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS` variable when the language detection module exits.

Unfortunately, there is no blessed way to override this list for `CXX` as it is hard-coded in `Modules/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake.in`.

Perhaps the best way of working around the actual error would be to use the `LANGUAGE` source file property to tell CMake how to compile the individual CUDA files, like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(kernels LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(Thrust REQUIRED)
thrust_create_target(Thrust FROM_OPTIONS)

thrust_is_cuda_system_found(USE_CUDA)
if (USE_CUDA)
  enable_language(CUDA)
endif()

set(cuda_kernel_sources my_kernels.cu)

add_library(cuda_kernels ${cuda_kernel_sources})
target_link_libraries(cuda_kernels PRIVATE Thrust)

if (NOT USE_CUDA)
  set_source_files_properties(
    ${cuda_kernel_sources}
    PROPERTIES
    LANGUAGE CXX
  )
endif ()
```

This will certainly be friendlier to other projects that might try to `add_subdirectory` yours.

---

*However*, if we want to be *very naughty*, we can do this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(kernels LANGUAGES NONE)

###
# Hacky language extension override

function(add_cuda_extensions variable access value current_list_file stack)
  if (NOT cu IN_LIST value)
    list(PREPEND "${variable}" "cu" "CU")
    set("${variable}" "${${variable}}" PARENT_SCOPE)
  endif ()
endfunction()

# verify CUDA support
include(CheckLanguage)
check_language(CUDA)
if (CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER AND NOT THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM STREQUAL "OMP")
  enable_language(CUDA)
  enable_language(CXX)
else()
  variable_watch(CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS add_cuda_extensions)
  enable_language(CXX)
endif()

###
# Normal project code starts here

message(STATUS "${CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS}")

find_package(Thrust REQUIRED)
thrust_create_target(Thrust FROM_OPTIONS)

add_library(cuda_kernels my_kernels.cu)
target_link_libraries(cuda_kernels PRIVATE Thrust)
```

This waits for the platform module to try to write `CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS` and then any time it's accessed, quickly inserts the `cu` and `CU` extensions to the list.

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic!  Thank you.

Comment: @ptb - you're welcome! I think the better way is the first one, but I had some fun coming up with the second way, so I thought I'd post it, lol.

Comment: hmm... Now I get a build error: `linker input file unused because linking not done`. I'm guessing I'm missing some flag.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm wondering if I should change them all to `.cpp` files and then set the language to `CUDA` if need be...

Comment: @ptb - That could work, too. Do you have a sample file I could use for `my_kernels.cu` to test? If so, add it to your question.

Comment: I'll try to come up with a simplified one that fails.  Though I also discovered that `clang` will interpret the `.cu` file as cuda so I think the only option is to rename my `.cu` to `.cpp` and set the language to `CUDA` following your example. So far that works on my linux and mac workstations with gcc and clang.